# Zend AMF and Flash Tutorials

Tags: php, flash, zend-amf

I'm trying to learn Zend AMF but with Flash instead of Flex. I've seen Lee Brimelow's introduction tut, but are there any others out there that cover things more in depth?

Cheers,
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [site](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Zend-Amf-and-class-mapping-with-Flash-CS3-AS3/43802) could help.